# add ID automatically in html page with RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex, html

In fact, I want a regular expression with function replace that allows me to add an ID just before the closing tag

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

brrr very slow

```
 [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'),function(item){item.id=setSomeUniqId()})
```

a u sure u need to set id for all element in page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you mean but it is a start, just execute the following js in the console:

```
var counter = 1; 
$('*').each(function() { $(this).attr('id', counter ); counter = counter  + 1; });
```

This gives all the elements on the page a numeric ID starting from 1, you can add something phrase in front of the numbers like this:

```
var counter = 1; 
$('*').each(function() { $(this).attr('id', 'element'+counter ); counter = counter  + 1; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This.. ?

```
var i = 0;
$('all of the awesome tags').each(function(){
   this.id = 'YAY' + (++i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery UI's [uniqueId()](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/):

```
$('*').uniqueId();
```